# get_categories devuelve un array no continuo, ¿qué he hecho mal?

Tags: php, wordpress

llevo trabajando un tiempo con wordpress y esto es la primera vez que me ocurre. Utilizo la función de wordpress **get_categories** para extraer las categorías padre de las entradas. El código que muestro a continuación lo empleo en el archivo category.php.

```
<?php $parent_categories = get_categories( array(
 'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0
 )); ?>

<?PHP VAR_DUMP($parent_categories)?>
```

Lo que me devuelve el **var_dump** es:

```
array (size=2)<br/>
  0 => 
    object(WP_Term)[38545]
      public 'term_id' => int 84

  2 => 
    object(WP_Term)[38546]
      public 'term_id' => int 16<br>
```

Muestra todos los campos de cada categoria pero no me parecia adecuado mostrar todos. Lo que me interesa es **¿por qué me devuelve array[0] y array[2] y no el array[1]?**

Update del codigo

```
<ul>
 <?php if( count($sub_categories) >= 1 ){
      $c = 0;

    while( $c<=count($parent_categories) ):

     $selected_all = ($category->slug == $parent_categories[$c]->slug )? 'class="selected"' : '';

        if($select_all != ''){break;}
           $c++;
    endwhile; ?>

    <li <?= $selected_all ?> >
        <a href="<?= get_category_link( $id_parent ) ?>">
            <h2><?= __('All','mgm') ?></h2>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>

<?php foreach($sub_categories as $sub_category){ ?>
    <?php $selected = ($sub_category->slug == $category->slug)? 'class="selected"' : '' ; ?>
    <li <?= $selected ?> >
        <a href="<?= get_category_link( $sub_category->cat_ID )?>">
            <h2><?= $sub_category->name ?></h2>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: ¿Puede que el elemento 1 sea parent != 0?

Comment: Pero si yo le paso por parametros la id del parent 0 en este caso, me tiene que devolver un array con los objetos que unicamente que concuerdan con ese parent y los ordenará dentro de la array en su hueco correspondiente según los encuentre. Quiero decir que será automático con un bucle o algo parecido, por eso no entiendo porque no funciona.

Comment: Si especificas parent = 0, entonces le estás diciendo que solo quieres los padres. Si lo quieres todo (con sus hijos), tienes que quitar ese parámetro.

Comment: Puede que tengas que añadir hide_empty = 0, según lo que desees que no sabemos.

Comment: Si quieres recorrer los elementos descartando el id del array, puedes hacer foreach($parent_categories as $cat) { echo $cat->name; }

Comment: Mi intención es únicamente conseguir los padres para poder hacer un while que necesito para comparar el contenido del slug. Vamos, que solo necesito el contenido de las categorias padres.

Comment: Entonces te vale el foreach, no necesitas un for con un contador *i* clásico, aunque también puedes usarlo mientras que $i <= count($parent_categories).

Comment: $i <= count($parent_categories), es lo que tengo hehcho y no me funciona

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos el código?

Comment: He actualizado el código, el problema esta en el while, lo demás va bien. Gracias.

Comment: No estoy seguro porque lo he mirado muy por encima, pero el código de dicha función: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/ muestra que el 0 y 2 de tu array, son las keys de las categorías, luego si creas la 0, luego la 1 hija de la 0 y después la 2 como padre, es normal que el array sea 0 y pase a 2, pues la hija no la muestras.

Comment: Lo siento pero no lo tengo claro, no se supone que busca dichas categorias (con parent 0) y luego las muestra creando un array con el contenido que devuelve? He estao mirando por encima el source de la función

Comment: Pues parece que no, ya que *_make_cat_compat( $categories[ $k ] );* siendo $k la parte key de un array_keys, sin depurar no podría decirte más.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Al final lo arreglé con tu sugerencia de un foreach. ;)

Comment: Claro! era lo más sencillo ;)